# sequelize incrementing id on validation error

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Sequelize is incrementing the id, even though it's not adding it into the DB.

For example for my user mode:

```
var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
},
```

If I run

```
var newUser = User.create({
        email: "a",
        password: "a"
    })
```

I get id 1, but if I run it again I get a validation error

next if I run it with a different email

```
var newUser = User.create({
        email: "b",
        password: "a"
    })
```

The id is 3, even though the db only has 2 enteries (id 1 and 3)

I don't quite understand why the id keeps increasing even though its not being added to the db. Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequelize isn't providing the `id` values, PostgreSQL itself is. Presumably Sequelize uses a `serial` type for the `id` column and that gets its values from a database sequence and from the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> Note: Because `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are implemented using sequences, there may be "holes" or gaps in the sequence of values which appears in the column, even if no rows are ever deleted. A value allocated from the sequence is still "used up" even if a row containing that value is never successfully inserted into the table column. This may happen, for example, if the inserting transaction rolls back. See `nextval()` in Section 9.16 for details.

You're trying to do an INSERT that violates your uniqueness constraint and there's your rolled back transaction.

You shouldn't waste time caring about the particular `id` values, they're unique numbers and that's all that matters.